# Solid angle of a closed surface: is the solid angle subtended by half the closed surface half of 4 $\pi$ steradians?

Tags: mathematics, integration

I think I worded the title poorly, but my question is this: I was visiting Wolfram's page on solid angles (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SolidAngle.html), where they provide two sample solid angle calculations. The first is the solid angle subtended by 1 side of a cube, and the result is $4\pi/6$, i.e. 1/6 of the total possible solid angle.

The next example is a tetrahedron, and the find the solid angle subtended by one of its faces to be $4 \pi / 4$. It seems, based on these two examples, that I perhaps

$$\Omega = \frac{\text{subtending area of closed surface}}{ \text{total area of closed surface}} \times 4\pi $$

Is this true at all for a closed surface?

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't true at all. As a trivial counter-example, consider a parallelepiped with edges of length $1$, $1$, and $2$, observed $1/2$ unit from the centre of one of the square faces: there the two square faces have equal areas, but they subtend different solid angles.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In general, the solid angle subtended at a point $\mathbf r_0$ by some surface $S$ is given by a surface integral over the surface:
$$
\Omega_S=\int_S \frac{1}{|\mathbf r-\mathbf r_0|^2}\frac{\mathbf r-\mathbf r_0}{|\mathbf r-\mathbf r_0|}\cdot\mathrm d\mathbf S
$$
This is sort of like what you propose (and indeed $\int_S\mathrm dS$ would give you the area), but it needs to take into account for the fact that (i) a little square of area subtends a smaller solid angle if it's far away, and (ii) the same happens if it is pointing at an angle.

For the symmetric cases you mention, this integral reduces to a simple fraction, exclusively due to symmetry considerations. In the general case, however, there's nothing for it beyond just integrating.

Comment: Another simple counter:  Two concentric half-spheres face-to-face, one having a tiny radius, the other a huge radius.  View from their common center.  The huge one has nearly all the surface area but subtends only half of the solid angle.